# how to show a "View" Table (SQL Table) in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I know how to show a REAL Table in ASP.NET such as

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var s = db.StaffInfoDBSet.ToList();
    return View(s);     
}
```

and in the viewController ...

```
@model IEnumerable<TrainingHourSystem.Models.StaffInfo>

    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StaffId)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UnitId)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.GradeId)
            </th>
```

but I don't know how to show a "View" Table (SQL Table) in ASP.NET ...

Comment: What is a View table ?

Comment: a selected table (as a view), but not a real table ...

Comment: You can just select the "View Table" like normal table. nothing different from "Real Table"

Comment: If you want to show a subset of columns, you can use the `Select` method in your LINQ expression with projection of only those columns and pass that to the view (use a view model)

Comment: it shows the error msg when I create a MVC5 controller.

'Unable to retrieve metadata for 'TSystem.Models.YSummary'.
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

TSystem.Service.YSummary:EntityType
'YSummary' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
YSummaryDBSet : EntityType: Entity Set 'YSummaryDBSet' is based on type 'YSummary'
that has no keys defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Create a Data Class like this

```
 [Table("your View table name", Schema = "your schema name")]
    public class vTest
    {
        [Key]
        public int TestAutoId{ get; set; }
        public string TestName{ get; set; }
        public string TestDescription { get; set; }
    }
```

The key annotation is for saying that this view table has primary key.But physically primar key will not be there for view table

Answer (score 1):

You can Add that view in your Database Context like a normal table.
The error you are getting because probably your view does not have a primary key.
There can be no table in Entity Framework without a primary key